# Show that this series tends to an integral

Tags: analysis

[image]

I've shown that the inverse exists but an unsure as to how to go about the second part. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Use the definition of integral as a limit if sums.

Comment: I cannot see the image. I don't know why? May I ask you to write it by Latex here?